# AngularJS Bootstrap-ui tabs to pull in dynamic content

Tags: arrays, ajax, json, angularjs

I have set up a Plunker here to demonstrate my app:

http://plnkr.co/edit/iIJVuIxspDRedN7ZXiTK?p=preview

```
<tabset>
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" select="getContent()" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
  <div ng-hide="!tabs.isLoaded">
  <h1>{{tab.title}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in tabs.content">
      <p>{{item}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="tabs.isLoaded"><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

What I would like to do is only show the relevant content under each tab, at the moment the way I have set it up is I am pulling in all content in both tabs.

What is the best way to configure this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this $scope.tabs.content=res.data;

to

```
$scope.tabs.content=res.data[0].fruit;
```

Here is updated plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/5Ng9PHkrluKUSzQhor34?p=preview